# I'm making a bookmark page

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I submit the form the page refreshes. It feels like e.preventDefault() isn't working but I know that's not the case.  I tried other options like e.stopPropagation() but I'm still coming to a road block. I'm not sure if it's the submit button or if its how I have something set up.
Can't really figure this one out.

```js
import $ from 'jquery'
import cuid from 'cuid'
import item from './items'
//FOCUS ON: CLICKING BOOKMARK HEAD TO OPEN DROP DOWN LIST


// <i class="fas fa-star"></i> THIS IS STAR ICON
// make star icon either appear as many as ratings value is
// or make 5 stars and have it change color according to target
// use a for loop and insert rating value into i < rating




function bookmarkTemplate(item) {

  let itemTitle = `<li data-item-id="${item.id}" class="bookmark-head">${item.title}, Rating: ${item.rating}</li>

        <ul id='bookmark-dropdown' class='hidden'>
            <li>${item.url}</li>
            <li>${item.desc}</li>
        </ul>
`

  return itemTitle

}
// function that shows how many stars are seen by rating

function dropDownForm() {
  return `
    <form id = 'bookmark-form' >

    <label for='title'>Title</label>
    <input id="title" name='bookmark-form' type="text" placeholder='Required' required>
    <label for='url'>Url</label>
    <input id="url" name='bookmark-form' type="url" placeholder='Required' required>
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea id="description" name='bookmark-form' placeholder='Recommended'></textarea>
    <label for='rate'>Rate</label>
    <select id='rate' name='bookmark-form' type="text">
        <option value="1">1 Star</option>
        <option value="2">2 Star</option>
        <option value="3">3 Star</option>
        <option value="4">4 Star</option>
        <option value="5">5 Star</option>
    </select>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
    <button class='cancel' type="reset">Cancel</button>

</form>`

}

function addButtonTemplate() {
  return `<button name='add' id='add' class='add'>Add</button>`
}

function createItem(title, desc, rating) {

  return {

    id: cuid(),
    title,
    desc,
    rating

  }

}


function handleAddItem() {

  console.log('addItem called')

  $('#bookmark-form').on('submit', (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()

    let titleValue = $('#title').val()
    let description = $('#description').val()
    let rating = $('#rate').val()
    item.items.push(createItem(titleValue, description, rating))
    let item = [...item.items]

    $('.bookmark-head-list').html(mapItems(item))

    console.log(titleValue)

  })
}

function getIdOfItem(current) {
  return $(current)
    .closest('.bookmark-head')
    .data('item-id')
}

// use this on delete
function findById(id) {

  return item.items.find(currentItem => currentItem.id === id)

}

function handleToggleHidden() {

  console.log('ran handleToggleHidden')

  $('.bookmark-head-list').on('click', '.bookmark-head', function(e) {

    let getId = getIdOfItem(e.target)
    console.log(getId)
    let id = findById(getId)
    $('.bookmark-head').children('#bookmark-dropdown').toggleClass('hidden')

    console.log(item.items)
  })

}
console.log(item.items)

function mainPageHTML() {
  return $('body').html(`<h1>Bookmark App</h1> ${addButtonTemplate()} <ul class='bookmark-head-list'></ul>`)
}

function addButtonClick() {
  $('body').on('click', '.add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    return $('body').html(`<h1>Bookmark App</h1> ${dropDownForm()} <ul class='bookmark-head-list'> </ul>`)

  })
}

function cancelButtonClick() {
  $('body').on('click', '.cancel', function() {
    console.log('cancel button clicked')
    return mainPageHTML()
  })
}
//see list of bookmarks in condensed view when app is open
//click on bookmark to display view
//make form collapse into bookmark head when submitted

function mapItems(i) {
  let item = i.map(item => bookmarkTemplate(item))
  return item.join('')

}



//receive feedback when unable to submit bookmark

//dropdown list <select> with a minimum rating filter to filter bookmarks at or above chosen rating


function render() {
  handleAddItem()
  mainPageHTML()
  cancelButtonClick()
  addButtonClick()
  handleToggleHidden()



}


// place 2 types of functions ones with handlers and functions that
// need to display on initial load
$(render)
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 30px;
}

input {
  height: 50px;
}

input[type='text'],
input[type='url'] {
  font-size: 30px;
}

textarea {
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 80px;
}

select {
  height: 40px;
  font-size: large;
}

button {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: large;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}


/* inside of rating add a star value for rating*/


/* stop forgetting about content: */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bookmark App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href='/src/styles.css'>

</head>

<body>
  <!--<div> id='add-form'></div>  this will be called through a button-->



  <script src='index.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, because I saw it might help: `.preventDefault()` works best when the function that calls its ALSO returns zero/false, I saw that not always happening here.  Cheers.

Comment: Hey, sorry for not responding sooner I was being stubborn and didn't want to bother with a stupid question but could you by chance help me find how to check if a function holds true or false? Thank you for this advice too. I had no clue the function had to be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no event delegation and to make it prettier there shouldn't be DOM manipulation inside of the function calling preventDefault().

```js
$('body').on('submit', '#bookmark-form', (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()

    let titleValue = $('#title').val()
    let description = $('#description').val()
    let rating = $('#rate').val()
    item.items.push(createItem(titleValue, description, rating))


 
  })
```

Comment: If you think that your question is not being treated properly, the best course of action is to either ask for clarification on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), or to flag your question for moderator intervention. It might be helpful to review the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), if you're unsure.

Comment: I'm glad to know there is more resources out there. I really appreciate it Tieson.